# Globally replacing short tags from all pages

Tags: regex, sed

I was looking to build a sed that would globally kill short tags in my scripts as there is a LOT of legacy stuff floating around that needs to be banished. I was working of a regex but it's being greedy so am looking for a non-greedy sed that will replace all occurances of

```
<\?=(.*)\?>        ## Pattern
<?php echo $1; ?>  ## Replacement
```

This WILL turn `<?=$foo?>` into `<?php echo $foo; ?>` but it will also turn `<?=$foo?><?=$bar?>` into `<?php $foo?><?=$bar; ?>` as well as duplicates the line of the match.

The SED looks like `sed -i -e "s/<?=\(.*\)?>/<?php echo \1; ?>/g" file`

My answer would assume that

```
<?=$foo?><?=$bar?>                      ## in
<?php echo $foo; ?><?php echo $bar; ?>  ## out
```

Comment: well if you're going to do it this way.. you don't really need to match for the closing tag or anything inbetween..`s/<\?=/<\?php/g`

Comment: That doesn't add a closing semicolon at the end though either =/ also the `=` should be an echo statement I just forgot to add it to the above code

Comment: i see. well then use a non-greedy match-all for the in-between stuff: `(.*?)`

Comment: Can't you use `perl -pe 's/<\?=((?:(?!\?>)[\s\S])*)\?>/<?php echo \1; ?>/g'`?

Comment: @stribizhev any way to detect whether there is a `;` and add it if not, per `<?php echo \1; ?>`

Comment: I guess `perl -pe 's/<\?=((?:(?!\?>)[\s\S])*?);?\s*\?>/<?php echo \1; ?>/g'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with

```
sed 's/<[?]=\([^?]*\)/<?php echo \1; /g' file
```

Comment: One small detail is that I believe `[^?]` should probably be `[^?>]` so you don't match `<?= ($foo) ? 'bar' : 'baz' ?>` or something? above will output `<?= ($foo) ; ? 'bar' : 'baz' ?>`

Comment: it is very difficult in sed to match non greedy more then one characters. One shortcut idea can be first to replace ?> with some 'unusable' character for ?

Comment: for example let that unusable character is '@'. then sed 's/?>/#>/g' first, after replacing with modified solution adding reverse sed 's/#>/?>/g'